# Is it possible to put MySQL database in single user mode?

Tags: mysql, database, t-sql, mysql5

How can I put a MySQL database in single user mode?
Or even better, in read mode only.

I use `select * into outputfile` in MySQL side and `bcp in` in Sybase side to pass data and I want them to be the same in both sides. So, I need the database to remain unchanged.

Is it possible?

Comment: Hope this helps... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886209/how-to-exclusive-lock-mysql-database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue a `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK` statement before you start to dump, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html for more information.

From the sited link:

> MySQL enables client sessions to acquire table locks explicitly for the purpose of cooperating with other sessions for access to tables, or **to prevent other sessions from modifying tables during periods when a session requires exclusive access to them**. A session can acquire or release locks only for itself. One session cannot acquire locks for another session or release locks held by another session.

Answer (score 1):

you can add `read_only=1` to **`my.cnf`** to put mysql into read only mode

alternatively, you can also `SET GLOBAL read_only=1;`

Comment: This does not lock the database from writes if it is a slave database. The simple solution would be to just issue a LOCK TABLES statement while the operation is performed.